# How can I bundle AntD the right way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, antd, parceljs

This would be my first time not using CRA for a project so following this guide [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app).

Under the heading `Customize Theme`. I'm trying to import ant.design default styling (**if possible not import styles if component is not imported?**) and be able to override it. I'm not sure exactly where to go from here. How can I implement less/less-loader section in my .babelrc?

Also I want to be able to take advantage of `babel-plugin-import` so that I can call on the component on demand as it looks like I am importing the entire lib.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    [
      "import",
      {
        "libraryName": "antd",
        "libraryDirectory": "es"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

[image: Edit Parcel Antd]

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue but I solved . Created a file webpackrc in root directory and paste following script

```
{
"extraBabelPlugins": [
["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "es", "style": "css" }]
]
}
```

or just try this one to import antd css -

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
```

To the top of either/both of App.css and Index.css.

Hope that helps!